# Windows crypto API

Tags: c, windows, cryptography, sha1

I'm having trouble with a function I made to create a sha1 hash of some strings. The function generates a valid hash for strings longer than 4 chars, but for chars less than that the hash is wrong. I've been looking all over for a solution but I can't see whats wrong.

```
int create_hash(char *plaintext, char *digest) {
char digest_buff[3];
DWORD buf_size = SHA1_HASH_LEN;
HCRYPTPROV prov;
HCRYPTHASH hash;
BYTE rgbHash[SHA1_HASH_LEN];
CHAR rgbDigits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
int i;

if(!CryptAcquireContext(&prov, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)) {
    if(DEBUG) {
        printf("CryptAcquireContext failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    return SHA1_FAILED;
}

if(!CryptCreateHash(prov, CALG_SHA, NULL, NULL, &hash)) {
    if(DEBUG) {
        printf("CryptCreateHash failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    return SHA1_FAILED;
}

if(!CryptHashData(hash, (BYTE *)plaintext, sizeof(hash), NULL)) {
    if(DEBUG) {
        printf("CryptHashData failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    return SHA1_FAILED;
}

if(!CryptGetHashParam(hash, HP_HASHVAL, rgbHash, &buf_size, NULL)) {
    if(DEBUG) {
        printf("CryptGetHashParam failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    return SHA1_FAILED;
}

for(i=0; i < buf_size; i++) {
    sprintf(digest_buff, "%c%c", rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4], rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf]);
    strcat(digest, digest_buff);
}

if(!CryptDestroyHash(hash)) {
    if(DEBUG) {
        printf("CryptDestroyHash failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    return SHA1_FAILED;
}

if(!CryptReleaseContext(prov, NULL)) {
    if(DEBUG) {
        printf("CryptReleaseContext failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    return SHA1_FAILED;
}

if(DEBUG) {
    printf("digest: %s\n", digest);
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: In what way is the hash wrong? Do you have another implementation you compared against?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CryptHashData` accepts the length of the ***data*** as third parameter, and you pass size of the hash buffer there. You need to pass smth like strlen(plaintext) there.

Comment: More specifically, you need to pass the byte-length (on the off chance you ever port this to wide-char-unicode, do yourself a favor and head off accidentally only hashing half the string). Oh, and if you're doing a sha1 you're gonna need 20 bytes to store the resulting hash, so you may want to size that appropriately.